# Canceling a contract without a cancelation clause

Tags: contract-law

Can a contract between a customer and vender without a cancelation clause be canceled without cause by the customer?

In other words... is an unmentioned clause open to do whatever anyone wants to do with it?

Comment: This answer contains neither a description of where this happened which determines which law applies, nor enough of a factual context to determine an answer. Legal questions are very fact specific and don't have general answers that apply everywhere. For example, the rule in U.S. and the U.K. are different on this subject. It matters if it was a consumer or commercial sale. It matters if it was goods, services or real property. It matters if the goods have been shipped or delivered or not. It matters why someone wants to cancel their order. It matters if it is a custom good or can be resold.

Comment: You may want to try to modify you question to provide more detail that makes it possible to answer.

Comment: Hi Chris - welcome. You should at the very least include the state or country you are interested in knowing the answer for. Also, actually, just see @ohwilleke recommendations above, he's spot on. More details, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably cannot be canceled.

A contract is a binding agreement, so unless the other party agreed to let you cancel the contract, you should generally consider yourself bound.

A variety of exceptions *might* apply, depending on the jurisdiction, circumstances, and timing of the cancellation, including:

- contracts entered into by a minor;
- contracts entered into by someone without mental capacity;
- contracts with a door-to-door salesman;
- contracts for a mortgage;
- contracts for certain personal services;
- contracts for a vehicle.